# Frequency step in psd_multitaper vs psd_welch

Tags: python, mne-python

The frequency step in the return values of [`psd_welch`](https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.time_frequency.psd_welch.html) is 1.953125 while in [`psd_multitaper`](https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.time_frequency.psd_multitaper.html) it is 0.00164441 -  3 orders of magnitude difference:

```
import mne
psds,freqs = mne.time_frequency.psd_multitaper(edf)
np.diff(freqs)
==> array([0.00164441, 0.00164441, 0.00164441, 0.00164441, 0.00164441, ...])
psds,freqs = mne.time_frequency.psd_welch(edf)
np.diff(freqs)
==> array([1.953125, 1.953125, 1.953125, 1.953125, 1.953125, 1.953125, ...])
```

Why? How do I control it?

PS. See also [discussion](https://mne.discourse.group/t/frequency-step-in-psd-multitaper-vs-psd-welch/5401?u=sds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## `psd_multitaper` - no go

The frequencies are determined by `edf.info["sfreq"]` which can only be changed by `edf.resample()` which also modified the upper frequency limit `edf.info["lowpass"]`.

## `psd_welch` - easy

Use `n_fft` argument. It defaults to 256. So, if you want to halve the step from 1.953125 to 0.9765625 pass `n_fft=512`.